# Radio buttons and display none

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an order form that when a button is clicked it displays an image in a separate div. The code works successfully for check boxes but with radio buttons doesn't hide the previously clicked image.

```
function displayImage(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el.style.display == "inline") {
        el.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        el.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

---

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="chkcheese" value="Yellow American" onclick="displayImage('imgamerican');" />
        <label for="chkcheese">Yellow American</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="cheese" value="Pepper Jack" id="pepperjack" onclick="displayImage('imgjack');" />
        <label for="chkjack">Pepper Jack</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="cheese" value="Mozzarella" id="chkmozz" onclick="displayImage('imgmozz');"/>
        <label for="chkmozz">Mozzarella</label>
    </td>
</tr>


<div class="cheese">
    <img id="imgamerican" src="images/american-cheese-slice.png" style="display:none"/>
    <img id="imgcheddar" src="images/agedcheddar.png" style="display:none"/>
    <img id="imgjack" src="images/pepperJack.png" style="display:none" />
    <img id="imgswiss" src="images/swisscheese.png" style="display:none" />
```

Comment: link to page  http://jrgraphicdesign.net/IM301/FinalProject/cheesesample.php

Comment: There won't be a "display" property on the element style unless it's explicitly coded into a "style" attribute in HTML.  You should add/remove a class from the elements instead, in my opinion.

Comment: @Pointy: It's in the style attribute. The ID being passed points to the images which have `style:"display:none"`

Comment: Still, adding and removing a class is a good idea.

Comment: @IHateLazy oh I'm sorry; I was looking at the radio buttons themselves durr :-)

Answer (score 1):

The click event only happens on the radio that was clicked.

You'll need to iterate the radio buttons and make sure that the deselected ones have their corresponding image hidden, or just iterate the images and hide them before showing the one that had its radio clicked.

```
function displayImage(id) {
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".cheese > img");

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "inline";
}
```

Comment: Indeed.
Or an easier way is to use one `<img>` element and swap the `src` attribute for the cheese image.

Comment: @Shourav: Very true, as long as more than one of the images are never intended to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you're expecting the `click` event to fire when a radio button becomes `unchecked`. But it doesn't. You'll need to specifically change the display of the last-shown cheese, but only when it's a radio button that was clicked.

This solution is kind of a hack, but it should work in this situation:

JavaScript:

```
var lastUnique;
function displayImage(id, unique) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);

    if (unique) {
        if (lastUnique) {
            lastUnique.style.display = 'none';
        }

        lastUnique = el;
    }

    el.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Radio buttons (note the added `true`):

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="cheese" id="chkcheese" value="Yellow American" onclick="displayImage('imgamerican', true);" />
  <label for="chkcheese">Yellow American</label></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="cheese" value="Pepper Jack" id="pepperjack" onclick="displayImage('imgjack', true);" />
  <label for="chkjack">Pepper Jack</label></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="cheese" value="Mozzarella" id="chkmozz" onclick="displayImage('imgmozz', true);" />
  <label for="chkmozz">Mozzarella</label></td>
</tr>
```

So, the JavaScript keeps track of the last element shown with the unique argument being truthy, and hides it when another call with `unique == true` happens.

**Aside:**

You might look into how event handling is done in the modern world. This is the old way of doing it, and it's not exactly manageable.

Also, consider looking into modularization and encapsulation techniques.